# Visual Studio LINQ for XML distinct list of child tags values

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I'm writing my first LINQ for XML query and not succeeding. I have the following code:

```
    Dim xmlIn = XDocument.Load("wiktionary.xml")

    Dim xmlOut = <namespaces>
                     <%= From ns In xmlIn...<mediawiki>.<page>.<ns>
                         Select ns %>
                 </namespaces>

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("wiktionaryout.xml", xmlOut.ToString, False)
    Process.Start("wiktionaryout.xml")
```

The XML is of the form

```
<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/ http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10.xsd" version="0.10" xml:lang="af">
  <siteinfo>
  ...
  </siteinfo>
  <page>
    <title>MediaWiki:Edithelppage</title>
    <ns>8</ns>
    <id>21</id>
  </page>
</mediawiki>
```

I'm trying to extract a distinct list of the values between the `<ns>` tags. Currently I'm just trying to get a list of all the values, but it just brings back

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<namespaces/>
```

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim ns As List(Of String) = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "ns").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).Distinct().ToList()
    End Sub

End Module
```